# Xcode archive error: Command actool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, swift, xcasset, xcode9.3

I got this error when archive app after upgrade to Xcode 9.3.
Here are some investigate result:

- Archive existing project, compile xcassets error
- Remove all image in xcassets, archive success
- Create new project and add image to xcassets, archive error

Do anyone has solution for this error? Thank you so much.

Error logs

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/nhuanvd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello-ahgsmtroieexmqahdahktbcsrozj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/hello/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/hello.app hello/Assets.xcassets
cd /Users/nhuanvd/Desktop/hello
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/nhuanvd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello-ahgsmtroieexmqahdahktbcsrozj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/hello/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/hello.build/Release-iphoneos/hello.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/nhuanvd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello-ahgsmtroieexmqahdahktbcsrozj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/hello/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/hello.build/Release-iphoneos/hello.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.nhuanvd.hello.sticker-pack. --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 11.3 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/nhuanvd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello-ahgsmtroieexmqahdahktbcsrozj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/hello/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/hello.app /Users/nhuanvd/Desktop/hello/hello/Assets.xcassets

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 255
```

**Some time, i get more error log with stack trace.**

```
2018-05-14 05:16:42.164 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[17346:326934] *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x1170e3c00) for message '' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime (0x7f86da381f60)-- abort
2018-05-14 05:16:50.258 ibtoold[16210:319259] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'IBPlatformToolFailureException', reason: 'The tool closed the connection

Last command:
_ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:

Backtrace of last command:
  0   -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1   __74-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  3   _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  4   DVTDispatchSync (in DVTFoundation)
  5   -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6   -[IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogToolProxy compileItemsWithCatalogRelativeIdentifierPaths:tagSolutionSpace:andStickerPacksWithCatalogRelativeIdentifierPaths:options:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7   -[IBAbstractCocoaTouchPlatformAdapter compileCARItems:tagSolutionSpace:options:queue:completionHandler:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8   __84-[IBICAbstractPlatformAdapter compileSelectedItems:options:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 10   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
 14   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 15   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 16   -[NSRunLoop(DVTNSRunLoopAdditions) dvt_spinRunLoopInMode:whileBlockExecutesConcurrently:] (in DVTFoundation)
 17   -[NSRunLoop(DVTNSRunLoopAdditions) dvt_spinRunLoopInMode:waitingForSemaphore:] (in DVTFoundation)
 18   -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona compileCatalogCollection:withPlatformAdapter:arguments:outputDictionary:] (in ibtoold)
 19   -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona invokeArguments:outputDictionary:] (in ibtoold)
 20   -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona runSingleInvocation:outputtingToFileHandle:andVerifyingEnvironment:] (in ibtoold)
 21   IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocation (in ibtoold)
 22   __IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess_block_invoke_2 (in ibtoold)
 23   __IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess_block_invoke (in ibtoold)
 24   -[IBCLIErrorForwarder forwardErrorOutputToDescriptor:whileInvokingBlock:] (in ibtoold)
 25   IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess (in ibtoold)
 26   main (in ibtoold)
 27   start (in libdyld.dylib)
'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3b64a6bb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62d56942 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3b64a609 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b1e260b -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:shouldRaiseOnFailures:waitForCrashLog:] + 1509
    4   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b1e1ffc -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy errorByAddingAdditionalCrashInformationToError:orRaiseIfNeededOnFailure:] + 94
    5   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b1e3475 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 221
    6   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b1e32b0 __74-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:]_block_invoke + 38
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63933e08 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63947231 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
    9   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010bc07ae7 DVTDispatchSync + 208
    10  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b1e31d5 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 245
    11  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000119df6b6b -[IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogToolProxy compileItemsWithCatalogRelativeIdentifierPaths:tagSolutionSpace:andStickerPacksWithCatalogRelativeIdentifierPaths:options:] + 220
    12  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration 0x0000000119dddbc7 -[IBAbstractCocoaTouchPlatformAdapter compileCARItems:tagSolutionSpace:options:queue:completionHandler:] + 940
    13  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010b137a80 __84-[IBICAbstractPlatformAdapter compileSelectedItems:options:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 228
    14  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010bc07b68 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 97
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6393b64a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63933e08 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6393f3e5 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3b603ea9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3b5c66ba __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3b5c5a07 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
    21  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010baab6f2 -[NSRunLoop(DVTNSRunLoopAdditions) dvt_spinRunLoopInMode:whileBlockExecutesConcurrently:] + 457
    22  DVTFoundation                       0x000000010baabb9a -[NSRunLoop(DVTNSRunLoopAdditions) dvt_spinRunLoopInMode:waitingForSemaphore:] + 128
    23  ibtoold                             0x000000010aeb2f37 -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona compileCatalogCollection:withPlatformAdapter:arguments:outputDictionary:] + 1601
    24  ibtoold                             0x000000010aeb475d -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona invokeArguments:outputDictionary:] + 1756
    25  ibtoold                             0x000000010aeb4bc6 -[IBCLIImageCatalogToolPersona runSingleInvocation:outputtingToFileHandle:andVerifyingEnvironment:] + 709
    26  ibtoold                             0x000000010aec21ed IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocation + 520
    27  ibtoold                             0x000000010aec2849 __IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess_block_invoke_2 + 34
    28  ibtoold                             0x000000010aec2719 __IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess_block_invoke + 864
    29  ibtoold                             0x000000010aeb1aef -[IBCLIErrorForwarder forwardErrorOutputToDescriptor:whileInvokingBlock:] + 110
    30  ibtoold                             0x000000010aec1da5 IBCLIServerRunSingleInvocationWithIODirectedAtPipesAndUnlinkOnSuccess + 589
    31  ibtoold                             0x000000010aec0bec main + 2638
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6396d015 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed issue by upgrading to Xcode 9.3.1. This might be Xcode issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to select the installed version under **Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools** as recommended in [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unable-to-create-project-using-arkit-and-ar-foundation-on-apple-silicon-m1-macbook.1302240/) thread. It was blank before.

Answer (score -1):

Had same problem with Xcode 9.4. Solved it by reinstalling Xcode.